# Move OS files to the begin of the disk

Tags: operating-system, defragmentation

I would like to know if it's possible to move the files on a given partition to the begin of the disk, where the read/writes are faster.

I currently have Windows Vista installed on the first partition of the disk with a few more partitions for work related files and other stuff.

Would this guarantee that the OS partition (which was the first to be created) is located at the begin of the disk?

Would a defrag program help with this or the various partitions limit the location of the files on the disk?

Comment: This question is not programming related. Ask over at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Two answers so far seem to have missed the point. You're asking whether the first partition (for Vista) physically prevents files on *other* partitions from being moved to the start of the physical disk, right?

Comment: Correct, Rob. Going in more detail, I was planning on installing Windows 7 RC on the available free space (I have 160 GB out of 320GB used so far) and later make it the primary OS, but if it will be installed at the middle or end of the disk there will be some speed penalty compared to the current vista installation. I just want to make sure I can move the most used files to the begin of the disk but since I have several partitions I not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I misread the question. Sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Physical partitions separate a disk into *circular* regions. The first partition occupies the outer ring of the disk, and the next partition occupies the ring inside that one. You can move files *within a partition*, but all the files of one partition come before any files of any other partition.

If partitions were wedge-shaped, then what you request would be possible.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I've been reading JDefrag forums and indeed the first partition is created at the start of the disk space, then the second one and so on. So I'll be needing to install the OS on the first partition to take advantage of the faster disk location.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate Defrag (sry, no link, just google it up, it's free) has the option to move recent used files to the fastest area of the disk

Greetz,
GHad